# Cache HTTPS-Responses in nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to cache responses from `https://example.com` (SSL/TLS !) with nginx, so basically a forward-proxy that caches a response for 10m.

I'm using docker with [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/reiz/nginx_proxy/) image, as it has the `ngx_http_proxy_connect_module` implemented.

Currently I have set it up like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
events { }

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;


    log_format cache_log '$remote_addr - $upstream_cache_status [$time_local]  '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    'URI: $request_uri - duration: "$request_time';

    access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log cache_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx_errors.log;


    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=inventory_cache:10m max_size=10g;

    server {
        listen       8888;
        server_name  xyz.com;
        proxy_connect;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        location / {
           proxy_cache inventory_cache;
           add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
           proxy_pass https://$http_host;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
    }

    # Everything else is denied
    server {
        listen       8888;
        server_name ~.+;
        return 404;
    }

}
```

I expected $upstream_cache_status to show the cache-status, but it's always `-` So I guess the caching is not happening.

Could it be due to SSL/TLS? I tried providing `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` but then I got the error unknown directive `ssl_certificate`.

I would prefer a solution with the normal nginx docker-image but I didn't manage to pass https requests. With the image I am using now, the https proxying works but not the caching..

So any solution is welcome, that caches responses form HTTPS servers. I wonder if this is not possible?

Or to phrase it differently: If a HTTPS-server, that I have no control over, has no caching enabled, how can I enable it for myself?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that in `nginx`, but your problem is caused by the specific configuration you're using, you have to change the way you configure your `SSL/TLS`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
events { }

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    log_format cache_log '$remote_addr - $upstream_cache_status [$time_local]  '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    'URI: $request_uri - duration: "$request_time';

    access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log cache_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx_errors.log;

    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=inventory_cache:10m max_size=10g;

    server {
        listen       8888 ssl;
        server_name  xyz.com;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/private.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
           proxy_cache inventory_cache;
           add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
           proxy_pass https://$http_host;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
    }

    # Everything else is denied
    server {
        listen       8888;
        server_name ~.+;
        return 404;
    }
}
```

be sure to replace `/path/to/your/certificate.crt` and `/path/to/your/private.key`

if that still dont work you can add the following in the `location` block

```
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
```